# ForceFully open all external links in InAppBrowser

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm using ionic 4 cordova.
I want to open all the external links to open in the inappbrowser only.
the External links may be dynamic and without any url specified the inappbrowser should open it restrict it not to open in the system browser in mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use
>
> window.location.href
>
> window.location.href =
> "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=1234567890", '_system';

Comment: Thanks Snehal, but what if the url is dynamic that we don't know what it will be!